# Composer not installing laravel 4 dependencies but working for other for eg twig

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, composer-php

I recently tried installing Laravel on my New VPS.
I installed lamp stack and installed composer too.

I tried composer install in laravel directory but it always stuck
showing

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

I waited almost 30 minutes but it doesn't work.
I am stuck at this point, I tried installing twig using composer in another folder and that worked fine.

my VPS has Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, 256mb ram, PHP 5.3.10 , apache2.2 , git is installed too.

Please let me know what could me the problem

Comment: Can you post the composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try installing Laravel through Composer instead.

`composer create-project laravel/laravel`

This will do everything you need to get a new Laravel project up and running in one line, which I wrote about as a [fast install for Laravel 4](http://www.neontsunami.com/post/laravel-4-the-fast-way).